# Ajax Not returning Data to Action ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC and facing a problem with accessing data via ajax in action of my ASP.NET Application.
Here is my Ajax Code:

```
$('.testBtn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        data: { id: 10 },
        url="@Url.Action("GetData", "Consultation")",
        success:function()
        {
        }
    });
});
```

And here is my action inside the controller:

```
public ActionResult GetData(int id)
{
    string x=id.ToStrring();
    return null;
}
```

For testing I am just passing a static integer and getting its value inside my action.

On clicking the button I am getting the following error:

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetData(Int32)' in 'careshade_mvc.Controllers.ConsultationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: Check your ajax type it's GET change it to POST and try

Comment: @Div problem still exists..

Comment: One more thing that you have to check, add `[HttpPost]` above your mvc method.

Comment: @Div Still not working ... It gives the following error:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult GetData(Int32)' in 'careshade_mvc.Controllers.ConsultationController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

Comment: What is your element with `class="testBtn"`? Is it a submit button (i.e your making both a normal submit and an ajax call?

Comment: Try this remove `type: 'GET',` from your script and put `breakpoint` on your method and check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.testBtn').click(function () {
            $.ajax(
              {
                  url: 'Consultation/GetData',
                  type: "POST",
                  data: { id: 10 },
                  success: function (result) {
                  }
              });
        });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

   <input type="button" class="testBtn" value="ClickHere" name="button"> 
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi @Div thanks for your effort but your code is also not working at my end. On clicking the button nothing happens.

Comment: @Bilal Amjad, make sure click is inside  `$(document).ready(function() { });`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var id = 10;
        $('.testBtn').click(function () {
        $.ajax(
          {
              url: 'Consultation/GetData/' + id,//instead data: { id: 10 },
              type: "GET",
              success: function (result) {
              }
          });
    });
    });
```

Comment: That would make no difference at all.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke. In my cases smotimes it do,

Comment: Ok, so do you have some proof? Because I use this solution in my code few times and it works and data: { id: 10 } not always. So why?

Comment: If you take the time to test the code in OP's question you will see that it works just fine (the most likely explanation is that OP is also making a normal form submit in addition to the ajax call)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a colon(:) character after `url` not the equals(=) sign.

**Simply change:**

```
url="@Url.Action("GetData", "Consultation")",
```

**To this:**

```
url:"@Url.Action("GetData", "Consultation")",
```

This was the only change I had to make to make the call work.Hope it helps you!